# Create a condition in order to count projects POWER BI

Tags: powerbi, conditional-statements, dax

I need to count a column that is called "Won/Lost/Not realized", the main column that will be counted is "Projects". The problem that I have is for each project sometimes I have Won and Lost or Won and No Realized,

so I would like to know how I can measure when the project is won once and not consider the other status.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bh8Qm.png)

Answer (score 0):

Use DISTINCTCOUNT('TableName'[ColumnName]) instead of COUNTROWS('TableName')?

Answer (score 0):

When you use `Table.Group`, you specify the aggregation column values by providing a formula that accepts, as a parameter, a table containing only the rows being grouped.

You can use this to group by project, so you have one row per project, then use the rows for that project to determine which status values to use, like so:

```ml
let
  Source = YourTable,
  GroupByProject = Table.Group(
    Source,
    "Project",
    {{
      "Status",
      // Formula to return best status among all rows in project
      each let
        // Unique list of non-blank status values for this project
        statuses = List.Distinct(List.RemoveItems(
          [Status],
          {"", null}
        )),
        // Power Query does lazy evaluation
        // so this is MUCH more performant than you might expect.
        BestKnownStatus = List.First(List.Intersect(
          // Expected statuses, in order of priority
          {"Won", "Lost", "Not Realized"},
          statuses
        )),
        Validated = if BestKnownStatus <> null then
          BestKnownStatus
        else if List.IsEmpty(statuses) then
          null
        else
          error Error.Record(
            "Unexpected Status",
            "Project had no expected status values but did have unexpected status values that you should probably adjust your query to handle.",
            [
              Subtable = _,
              statuses = statuses
            ]
          )
      in
        Validated
    }}
  )
in
  GroupByProject
```

### Explanation of `each`

If you aren't aware, an expression like

```
each [Status]
```

is just shorthand for

```
each _[Status]
```

which is shorthand for

```
(_) => _[Status]
```

and equivalent to

```
(tbl) => tbl[Status]
```

so, in the code I provided, `[Status]` returns a list of the "Status" column values for all rows in a given project.

Keep in mind that this code

- assumes your project numbers are in a "Project" column
- assumes your status values are in a "Status" column
- is meant as pseudo-code to explain the technique. It might work perfectly, but it may have syntax errors and other bugs, I didn't fire up Excel or PowerBI for this answer.